# Why U_mass coherence score decrease with topic number increase in Gensim

Tags: gensim

U_mass coherence calculated by Gensim and STM shows that the score decreases with the increase of topic number. But according to the formula of U_mass, a large value should be preferenced and the value should increase (closer to zero) with the increase of topic numbers. Why does it decreases?

Comment: Which reference suggests a larger `u_mass` score is preferred, or that the value "shoudl increase" with more topics? (I can find other discussion and graphs reporting that it decreases, including becoming more negative if already below zero, with more topics.)

Comment: "A larger u_mass is preferred" can be found in official paper of Mimno et. al. (2011).

Comment: Do you have a link? Are you sure that paper is using the same definition as implemented in Gensim? Again, other discussions imply that a smaller number, into negative values with no special role of zero, is expected with more topics.

Comment: Hi thank you! I double check the code and for Gensim u_mass coherence score, I am sure that it follows the paper. Let me know if you know that it is not. And would you mind sharing the discussions.

Comment: My understanding is that Gensim's coherence implementations come via a port from Palmetto (https://github.com/dice-group/Palmetto/wiki/Coherences), & follow the unifiying-framework from <http://svn.aksw.org/papers/2015/WSDM_Topic_Evaluation/public.pdf>, whihc *might* differ in effective-range than the original 2011 UMass definition. (In particular, its graphs show values < -240, whereas other graphs/discussion suggest a usual range far closer to 0.)

Comment: Is it possible the confusion is resolved by the observations: (a) generally, larger numbers mean better coherence; but also (b) generally, at some points, more topic mean worse coherence, and thus a falling value? That is, the incorrect assumption is that more topics necessarily means better coherence? If you could show more of your observations on your data, and/or contrast with similar coherence/topic-number trends with some public dataset, it might shed more light on what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! And sorry for the late response. The difference between Roder et al 2015 and Mimno is that Roder et al selected a smaller parameter Epsilon. How coherence score change with the improvement of model performance is still the same.

Comment: "(a) generally, larger numbers mean better coherence; but also (b) generally, at some points, more topic mean worse coherence, and thus a falling value?" I think this is highly possible. I am trying to do some simulation studies and see whether this argument is correct! Thank you!